# How to get a list of available `defaults write` terminal commands for OS X El Capitan (expert / superuser)

Tags: terminal, macos

I would like to know where I can find a list of all possible `defaults write` terminal commands.
(Core OS X related commands, not any due to user installed software.)

Here is an example command (which doesn't work in El Capitan by the way) which demonstrates

```
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse MouseHorizontalScroll -bool NO
```

Comment: These commands write to the property list fines inside of `~/Library/Preferences`.

Comment: There is no such list. The documentation for preferences is here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/UserPreferences.html

Comment: Well there obviously is. Big companies like Apple don't write an OS and not document it.

Comment: You can believe whatever you'd like. It's possible Apple has an internal document like this, but no such public document exists. These are hidden settings that are not intended to be set by the user, hence the fact they require a Terminal command to use. "Big companies like Apple" generally don't write manuals of hidden commands that they don't intend for the user to access.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Rather than ask for such a large list - is there something you are trying to do or something you wish to learn/understand?

Comment: Awkward when someone says welcome to [insert SO site here] - why do you think I added the initial comment at the top of this post?

Comment: I don't know why you added the initial comments. Usually it's when someone knows they are asking something that's either off topic or not clearly researched and it invites comments to clarify. Same with the welcome - it invites dialog. Sorry if you felt the greeting was awkward.

Comment: It's okay I added it to try and shield against the many responses on this site which get posted by people who haven't got a clue what they are talking about. It happens regularly on this site - a response which is written by someone who doesn't understand the question gets posted and everyone else goes "okay there's an answer I'll ignore the question now"

Comment: Thing is, if you start with the wrong attitude ie, expecting that no-one knows as much as you do & it is almost beneath your dignity to even have to ask us - then you're not going to get much in the way of happy responses. Having got that off my chest, try this...  http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/195290/85275 - I can claim nothing but half-decent Google Fu.

Comment: It's not that Im just aware the internet is plagued by people who don't know what they're talking about. Clearly in this case the right sort of people responded. It probably wouldnt have played out that way had I not included the top comment.

Comment: Well if anyone is wondering, here's the closest thing to what you're looking for that I could find: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.macos

Comment: `defaults read`

Comment: Sadly, defaults read won't show anything interesting—only the settings which you already changed via the UI (in which case, you could just use the UI) or via defaults write (in which case, you already know the command). Honestly, the best way to find the good ones is to use Hopper.

Comment: You can view the list (depending on your shell client; I have zsh) by typing `defaults write ` (keep the space on end of right) in the Terminal application, and then clicking `Tab ↹` on your keyboard. You should then get a prompt asking you if you want to see all possibilities. Click `Y` on your keyboard, and hopefully you will get the full available list.

Answer (score 5):

This is like asking for a list of all possible websites or all possible registry settings. These commands write to Apple and non-Apple software, and will vary depending on the apps/services installed and their versions.

Since this isn't a single unified settings database, I wouldn't assume Apple maintains a single document or manual on the settings.

Comment: Well it's not is it. There are some core commands for OS X El Capitan. Those are the ones I am interested in.

Comment: Well that's very specifically not what you asked.

Comment: See the above - it says explicitly OS X El Capitan

Comment: There are multiple versions of El Cap, depending on point-updates and security patches. But the point is, OS X isn't a single piece of software. It's a lot of components written across many teams. And, in any case, I don't believe such a list as you have requested is available. Your insistence that there must be does not make it so.

Comment: Okay so let's assume that's true and ask a more focused question. Where's the list for everything associated with mouse drivers. EG: as in example above

Comment: @user3728501, Even if there is a _master list_ or _sub lists_ of all possible settings in .plist files, Apple, to my knowledge, hasn't openly published them, nor do I believe they would do so either. Aside from anything you might find in Apple Developer Documentation, the rest will need to be gleaned from the Internet. That's just the way it's been.

Comment: That may be true in which case the answer is apple didn't publish it because they didn't expect their users to be able to cope with such things. Which brings a new question: how did the command above become known?

Comment: If you have another question you should probably open up a new thread as such.

Comment: @user3728501, Apple is known for not openly publishing considerable reams of documentation and it has absolutely nothing to do with users coping abilities.  The `defaults` command first appeared in NeXTStep before Steve Jobs came back to Apple and its purchase of NeXTStep.

Answer (score 1):

Things like this aren't always documented. I've seen keys change between minor versions as well as major ones, which adds to the difficulty in creating/maintaining such a document.

In this case, the key you're using `MouseHorizontalScroll` is still correct it's not working in the latest version.  :(  I've heard this is working in the latest seeds of macOS Sierra, though.