# Do macOS default preferences ever have breaking changes (the ones we edit with defaults command)?

Tags: macos, system-settings, plist, defaults

I have a script that uses the `defaults` command to set a bunch of preferences.

I am curious, do these preferences ever have breaking changes (f.e. when I update macOS), so that I need to modify my script?

If so, where can I find a list of breaking changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any part of the OS, Apple can change or modify the preference keys. Anecdotally, I can certainly remember people commenting that some keys have been removed, so that setting a particular preference no longer works.

For instance, Apple changed `PMPrintingExpandedStateForPrint` to `PMPrintingExpandedStateForPrint2` at some point. This is the key that specified whether the print dialog is expanded or simplified.

[As mentioned on this site before](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251356/how-to-get-a-list-of-available-defaults-write-terminal-commands-for-os-x-el-ca), Apple does not document many of the available keys; most of which have been found by inquisitive people searching for text strings in executables. So a list of changes seems unlikely.

The `defaults write` command does not check for validity. So I can add the key `IamFabulous -bool true` to Preview's plist, and it will sit there doing nothing. Preview will never check for the value of that key. Any 'defunct' key/value will act similarly.

Comment: Good to know it's at least harmless to have the old keys set.