# How to raise `LowBatteryNotificationPercentage` and `CriticallyLowBatteryNotificationPercentage` of Bluetooth devices?

Tags: keyboard, battery, bluetooth, mouse

I use a Magic Mouse and Magic Keyboard, which go for weeks or months at a time without needing a charge, and then they notify my when they're right on the verge of shutting down. After a lot of exploring here and stackoverflow (it seems the `ioreg` parameters have evolved since [most posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36679405/magic-mouse-battery-status-in-menubar) were written), I see there is a command which gives me visibility of the current battery level:

```
ioreg -r -l -k "BatteryPercent"
```

... which produces output which includes:

```
+-o AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService  <class AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService, id 0x100000635, registered, matched, active,$
{
  "LowBatteryNotificationPercentage" = 2
  "BatteryPercent" = 11
  "CriticallyLowBatteryNotificationPercentage" = 1
}
```

If I could increase those notification percentages to say 5% and 10%, then they'd mean *"hey, don't forget to put me on charge when you're done for the day"*, whereas right now they mean *"uh, oh, you probably won't make it to lunchtime!"*.

I've explored the output of `defaults export /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth` and indeed all of defaults, thanks to [this AskDifferent answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/198336), but can find nothing that looks like a way of setting the level at which the notifications are triggered.

I'd prefer not to need to install and have running a 3rd party tool to simply raise a watermark.